# iOS- MKMapKit-How would I drop an annotation on the users location?

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

I have the users location on my app, but how would I drop an annotation on the current user location? Would I have to get the long & lat of the users location and drop an annotation that way? or how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First import the necessary frameworks (CoreLocation and MapKit).
2. Then create the Objective-C NSObject class Annotation
3. Setup its .h:

   ```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

   #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

   @interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> 

   @property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

   @end
   ```
4. Setup its .m:

   ```
   #import "Annotation.h"

   @implementation Annotation
   @synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

   @end
   ```

   1. Setup `viewDidLoad`

      ```
         if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {

         locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

         [locationManager setDelegate:self];

         [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy: kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];

         [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

         }

        self.mapView.delegate = self;
      ```
   2. Setup the `didUpdateToLocation`

      ```
         // IMPORT ANNOTATION

         - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


         [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

         double miles = 3.10686;
         double scalingFactor = ABS((cos(2 * M_PI * newLocation.coordinate.latitude / 360.0)));

         MKCoordinateSpan span;

         span.latitudeDelta = miles/69.0;
         span.longitudeDelta = miles/(scalingFactor * 69.0);

         MKCoordinateRegion region;
         region.span = span;
         region.center = newLocation.coordinate;

         [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

         Annotation *annot = [[Annotation alloc] init];
         annot.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;

         [self.mapView addAnnotation:annot];

           }
      ```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set `showsUserLocation` to `YES` on your `MKMapView` and implement

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01));
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

in your `MKMapViewDelegate` to have the map view move to that location when the user's location has been found.

This will show a blue dot on the map view at the user's location like the Maps app does.